# Naming conventions for kegg nodes with multiple genes

Tags: python, kegg

So I'm downloading XML files from Kegg using BioConductor and and I'm running into a problem. If we look at [HIF-1 signaling pathway](https://www.genome.jp/pathway/hsa04066) we see the node [growth factor (GF)](https://www.kegg.jp/entry/hsa:1950+hsa:3479+hsa:3630) on the left hand side, we can trace it's XML entry to this entry:

```
    <entry id="17" name="hsa:1950 hsa:3479 hsa:3630" type="gene"
        link="https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:1950+hsa:3479+hsa:3630">
        <graphics name="EGF, HOMG4, URG..." fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
             type="rectangle" x="87" y="272" width="46" height="17"/>
    </entry>
```

While there is no GF on this, there are the three info card links that I can use to extract information. However, when I click on that link, there isn't a place on those info cards that says that these three genes are related to that general title of GF.

Normally this isn't a problem, I would just look at the map, but I'm trying to do something at scale where I can't look at every instance of this.

So my question is, how do I find the labels that Kegg uses in its map using the XML file/python package?

Comment: Python's `Bio.KEGG.Gene` has an attribute called `name` described as "A list of the gene names". Might help? Otherwise "orthology" is its own universe. Last ditch attempt try `beautifulsoup` and webscraping. In theory webscraping will work because if you can access the links via clicking them `beautifulsoup` will do this too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the `name` attribute! I'm trying to avoid scrapping at all costs cause this particular use case won't be pretty, but if it's all there is then...

Comment: How do you download the files from KEGG with Bioconductor? It might be easier to use Bioconductor to retrieve the gene names

Comment: If you used KEGGREST you should be able to retrieve the gene names of each pathway: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/KEGGREST/inst/doc/KEGGREST-vignette.html

Comment: The problem with the name attribute is that it returns multiple names for each card inside that node. GF for example returns `insulin`, `insulin like growth factor 1`, and `epidermal growth factor`. Which one do I use? and how did the original map just label it as `GF` (growth factor)?